# How to log all events in my Laravel application

Tags: laravel, logging

I would like to log all events in my app like:

```
User 1 - created a new item - created_at...
User 2 - deleted item  213- created_at...
etc.
```

I don't really see how am I supposed to do it.

Is there any plugin that should help?

Comment: You can setup Event Handling, and log from there

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) for this. These events will fire **before** or **after** any data will be **saved into** or **restored from** a database.

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into various
> points in the model's lifecycle using the following methods: creating,
> created, updating, updated, saving, saved, deleting, deleted,
> restoring, restored. Events allow you to easily execute code each time
> a specific model class is saved or updated in the database.

Comment: ok. but is kind of heavy defining in all my models those method, knowing that this method will be the same for all models

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but you could try to use `Model::created()` as far as all models extend this class.

Comment: there is not such a reference here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events
Where should I call it?

Comment: I do not mean Events, I mean Eloquent Events. Click a link from my answer, there are some examples there.